# How to increase the size of the /opt file system in the global zone of smartOS running in VMWare?

Tags: solaris, zfs, smartos

I downloaded joyent's smartOS vmware image and got that running.  Now I would like to increase the size of /opt because they were pretty stingy with it in the vm.

In the vm's settings, I expanded the disk to 35Gb.  But I don't know how to grow the zfs volume from inside smartos.

If this is not possible, is it possible to create new smartos zones on disks other than the /opt filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check, that you have backup (not zfs @snapshot).

Then you need to expand disk label via interactive `format` util.

If you have already done this, then you could expand ZFS pool.

How to expand ZFS pool.

get pool name

```
# zpool list
```

get all possible settings for pool

```
# zpool get all PoolName
....
PoolName  autoexpand     off                         default
....
```

set autoexpand option to 'on'

```
# zpool set autoexpand=on PoolName
```

ZFS pool will grow at this moment, you will see it in

```
# zpool list
```

To see size of opt dataset you may use command

```
# zfs list
```

If opt will not grow, then check its quota and edit it via `set`:

```
# zfs get quota
```

Return option to previous state

```
# zpool set autoexpand=off PoolName
```

Comment: My answer is based on my experience with SPARC Solaris with ZFS and searching some base information about smartos on their site smartos.org (i found info about `format` on it). So i have not deal with smartos, but it should work i think.